# Free abelian group on prime divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Can someone tell about how it is possible to write locally finite sets $n_{Z}$ [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BE0#:%7E:text=A%20Weil%20divisor%20is%20a%20formal%20sum%20D,the%20Weil%20divisor%20associated%20to%20a%20rational%20function) with the free abelian group generated by the prime divisors?

First I thought it was a cartesian product of spaces but it is in a free abelian group, so I dont know how to continue.

It looks like I use the prime divisors to generate the locally finite subsets, is that all I have to do ?

Comment: Here, $n_Z$ is the coefficient of $Z$ in the free abelian group generated by prime divisors $Z$. Is your question what a free abelian group is?

Comment: Well It sort of is; the coefficient looks to be a subset of what's generated the free group. So how would I actually write that coefficient /  locally finite set in the free group ?